# how to extend nuxt router to add new pages?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm on Nuxtjs v.2.15.4 and I'm trying a theming method for pages. by this code I can overwrite existing pages by my theme's pages :

```js
// nuxt.config.js
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    if(process.env.THEME === "mainTheme" && process.env.THEME_CUSTOMIZE === "false"){
      return
    }
    routes.map(route => {
      const path = resolve(`src/themes/${process.env.THEME}/${route.chunkName}.vue`)
      if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        route.component = path
      }
      if(process.env.THEME_CUSTOMIZE === "true"){
        const pathCustom = resolve(`src/themes/customs/${route.chunkName}.vue`)
        if (fs.existsSync(pathCustom)) {
          route.component = pathCustom
        }
      }
      return route
    })
  }
},
```

I know that where I check for existing path , must push to router if it doesn't exist. But what is the code that can do the naming and other thing like nuxt itself?
this is the code provided by nuxt doc to push into router:

```js
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
      name: 'custom',
      path: '*',
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/404.vue')
    })
  }
}
```

the `component` will be `resolve(`src/themes/${process.env.THEME}/${route.chunkName}.vue`)` like overwriting code, but what about `name` and `path` ?? specially when page is dynamic!!

**UPDATE**

Ok, I think this approach has a problem. It will check routes and if there is same in theme folder it will overwrite. but won't check the theme's page directory itself for other pages that doesn't exist in main pages directory!! So some how I must check the theme's pages dir and map through theme and overwrite main of add new. SO HOW !??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I solved it, but it's so messy and ugly!! also increases the build time !!

```js
// nuxt.config.js
// using glob: const glob = require("glob");

router: {
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    if(process.env.THEME === "mainTheme" && process.env.THEME_CUSTOMIZE === "false"){
      return
    }else{
      if(process.env.THEME !== "mainTheme"){
        let themePages = glob.sync(`src/themes/${process.env.THEME}/pages/**/*.vue`)
        routes.map(route => {
          const path = resolve(`src/themes/${process.env.THEME}/${route.chunkName}.vue`)
          if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
            route.component = path
            let regexp = new RegExp(process.env.THEME+'/'+route.chunkName+'.vue');
            themePages.splice(themePages.findIndex((x)=>{return x.match(regexp)}),1)
          }
          return route
        })
        themePages.map((x)=>{
          let str = x.split(process.env.THEME+'/')[1]
          routes.push({
            name: str.replace('pages/','').replace(/\/_|\//gi,'-').replace('.vue',''),
            path: str.replace('pages','').replace(/_(\w+)/gi,':$&?').replace(/:_/gi,':').replace('.vue',''),
            component: resolve(x),
            chunkName: str.replace('.vue','')
          })
        })
      }
      if(process.env.THEME_CUSTOMIZE === "true"){
        let customPages = glob.sync(`src/themes/customs/pages/**/*.vue`)
        routes.map(route => {
          if(process.env.THEME_CUSTOMIZE === "true"){
            const pathCustom = resolve(`src/themes/customs/${route.chunkName}.vue`)
            if (fs.existsSync(pathCustom)) {
              route.component = pathCustom
              let regexp = new RegExp('customs/'+route.chunkName+'.vue');
              customPages.splice(customPages.findIndex((x)=>{return x.match(regexp)}),1)
            }
          }
          return route
        })
        customPages.map((x)=>{
          let str = x.split('customs/')[1]
          routes.push({
            name: str.replace('pages/','').replace(/\/_|\//gi,'-').replace('.vue',''),
            path: str.replace('pages','').replace(/_(\w+)/gi,':$&?').replace(/:_/gi,':').replace('.vue',''),
            component: resolve(x),
            chunkName: str.replace('.vue','')
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
},
```